# Stata - How to get residuals for original equation using estimates for differenced equation

Tags: stata

I have variables `y`, `x1` and `x2`. I estimate a differenced equation (without the intercept) using `reg d.(y x1 x2), nocons`. Now I want to get the residuals for the original variables using the estimated coefficients. I can do it by

```
reg d.(y x1 x2), nocons
matrix b = e(b)
gen resid = y - b[1,1]*x1 - b[1,2]*x2
```

But would there be an easier way? I need to keep those generated residuals for future use. Here is a complete minimal example.

```
clear all
set obs 100
gen id = floor((_n-1)/5)+1
by id, sort: gen year = 1990+_n
xtset id year
set seed 1
gen x1 = rnormal()
gen x2 = rnormal()
gen y = rnormal()
*** Data generated ***
reg d.(y x1 x2), nocons
matrix b = e(b)
gen resid = y - b[1,1]*x1 - b[1,2]*x2
```

I wonder if there is a flexible approach because sometimes I want to completely change variable names for the regression (e.g., `reg dy dx1 dx2, nocons` not just `reg d.(y x1 x2)`). I thought perhaps `predict` might be helpful but I don't know. Would it be possible to avoid typing the variable names explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict` will not work since it will create residuals on the differenced scale. You want residuals in terms of the original y, which is unusual, so there is no off-the-shelf solution.

I think the easiest path is to do something like this:

```
reg d.(y x1 x2), nocons coefl
local vars:colnames e(b) // get a list of coefficients
foreach x of local vars {
    local xvar = subinstr("`x'","D.","",1) // strip out the D. prefix from the coefficient names
    local diff "`diff' - _b[`x']*`xvar'"
}
gen resid = y `diff'
```

If you have covariates like dx1 and dx2, you can modify the prefix stipper like this:

```
local xvar = subinstr("`x'","d","",1) // strip out the first d prefix
```